# Bot Telegram con Python conectado a MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, telegram

Hola he empezado un proyecto con un bot para telegram el cual debe ser desarrollado con Python y debe de hacer consultas a MySQL pero la vdd no tengo conocimiento del tema pero quisera saber si ¿Hay manera de realizarlo?

Tengo conocimiento en Python y MySQL pero, no en la creación de bot Para telegram como le he descrito arriba.

De ante mano muchas gracias por su atención y su ayuda.

Comment: Santiago la pregunta es demasiado amplia según las normas del sitio. Ten en cuenta que la idea es publicar preguntas  sobre problemas **concretos** de programación y que no den lugar a debates de opinión. Las preguntas del tipo ¿es posible...?, ¿cómo podría...?, etc rara vez van a ser bienvenidas. Otra cosa sería que mostraras un problema sobre un código determinado. Una búsqueda en Google te mostrá bastante información, con ejemplos y tutoriales incluso: https://www.google.es/search?q=telegram+bot+python&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=x_5nWcTVN5yF4gT064uwDw. Saludos.

Comment: Ok si perdón lo que pasa es que no sabía como formularla así que tuve que explicar.

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionan tu pregunta es muy amplia, mas sin embargo puedo responder que hay muchas formas de hacer tu bot para Telegram, yo lo que haria es usar BotFramework con NodeJS y hacer la parte de negocio con python y que botframework haga las consultas a tu backend hecho con Python.

Otra cosa que debes de ver es la documentación de Telegram, y como usar el BotFather, saludos.

BotFramework: https://dev.botframework.com/
Doc Telegram Bot: https://core.telegram.org/bots

Comment: Ok empezaré a documentar sobre la fuentes que me pasaste gracias